# IOS: Which is the best way to download a Large size file from server

Tags: ios

I have a **zip file** which contains db. i need to download that zip file when the user open the app at first time.So am using

```
NSData *urlData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlToRequest];
```

to download a file in GCD mode. Since it's working fine,am not getting any errors.

But, is it ok to download a large File using the above method or we have to use `NSURLConnection` for large file download. Please advice.

Comment: To get your answer read Discussion of dataWithContentsOfURL :https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1547245-datawithcontentsofurl

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. After i went through , i will implement with NSURLConnection because dataWithContentsOfURL will not handle large file size download.even though, am download only a Zip file which has only max of 20MB. If it raises in future it may cause a problem for download, hence i moved to NSURLConnection.

Comment: NSURLConnection is old. You should go with NSURLSession.. NSURLSessionDownloadTask is best for your need. Go through this articles to get Basic ideas of networking: http://code.tutsplus.com/series/working-with-nsurlsession--mobile-22700

Comment: If you are ok with third party code in your project, I suggest AFNetworking(https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: I second the recommendation to use download task (`NSURLSession`'s `downloadTaskWithURL`). It avoids loading the file into memory during the download, but rather writes it directly to persistent storage. And when you're ready to get advanced, you can use background session to continue download of the zip file even after the user leaves your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You should use NSURLSession => NSURLSessionDownloadTask api**

**What is wrong with below for large file download**

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlToRequest];
```

- Since, you are having large file to download which take huge time, thus more chances of connection break or any other interruption, which won't be resumed from last downloaded progress
- In case of a Large file, user should be provide an ability to pause and resume, above won't support that.
- Background downloading is also not supported
- Progress Status is not supported, which is very important for users, so as to keep them waiting on your app.

---

**Now, NSURLSession => NSURLSessionDownloadTask supports all of the above.**

Follow this nice tutorial:

[NSURLSession Tutorial:](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @gunjot singh